# Как в Notepad++ удалить в каждом слове предложения все буквы кроме первой?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как в Notepad++ удалить в каждом слове все буквы кроме первой?

Comment: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте следующее регулярное выражение:

```
\B\w+
```

Строку замены следует оставить пустым.

Шаблон `\B\w+` находит позицию, отличную от границы слова (`\B`), а затем `\w+` находит 1 и более букв/цифр или знаков подчёркивания.

Если нужно удалить только буквы в буквенных словах, используйте `\B[[:alpha:]]+\b` или `\B[[:alpha:]]+` (в последнем нет проверки на правую границу слова).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Используйте в `Найти` регулярку: `\b(\w)\w+\b`, а в `Заменить`: `\1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание регулярки:

- `\b` ищет границы слова
- `\w` ищет буквы, цифры, _
- (\w) захватывает в группу символ
- \1 имеет значение первой группы (в нашем случае это символ)

---

Было:

> Как в Notepad++ удалить в каждом слове все буквы кроме первой?

Стало:

> К в N++ у в к с в б к п?

Comment: Плюсики остались :) (они не буквы, согласен)